# Retornar vista como resultado de una función

Tags: laravel

Estoy haciendo una función donde me gustaría retornar una vista especifica al obtener determinado resultado. Como muestro en mi función, si obtengo que flag es igual a 1, me retorne una vista como resultado o caso contrario, me retorne otra vista distinta. La problemática es que no se si sea posible retornar vistas como resultado y si es posible de que forma se hace. Estoy utilizando la versión 5.5 de laravel.

```
public function checkOrganismo($id){
        $subtipo = $this->show($id);
        $tipos = Organismo::where('estatus',1)->get();
        $flag=0;
        $cont=0;
       for($c=0; $c < count($tipos);$c++){
            if($tipos[$c]->nombre==$subtipo->nombre) $cont++;
        }
        if($cont>0) $flag=1;

        if($flag==1){
            //Retornar vista
        }
        else{
            //Retornar vista diferente
        }
    }
```

Comment: Prueba con `return view('ruta.vista');`

Comment: No veo el error dejaste mocho el comentario

Comment: Disculpa, di click a enter por error, lo acabo de intentar, puse un console.log para ver que me retornaba y si me retorna la vista(en texto plano en la consola), mas no me redirecciona hacia ella, no se si me explico. Eso es lo que busco que me redireccione directo a la vista.

Comment: console.log() ?? eso no lo estás haciendo en el controlador ??

Comment: No, lo que pasa es que esa función del controlador la estoy tomando con angular, de esta forma:
    `$scope.check = function($id){     
           $http.get('/checkOrganismo/'+$id)
           .then(function success(response){
            $scope.checar = response.data;
            console.log($scope.checar);
            return $scope.checar;
        });
    };`
entonces con ng-click, mando a llamar la función de angular, que a su vez obtiene el resultado de mi función en laravel.

Comment: Entonces devuelve la ruta que hayas registrado en routes y con un window.location.href = "ruta" la redirijes

Comment: ¿En mi controlador tendria que retornar el nombre tal cual de la ruta? es decir: 
-return "nombreDeMiRuta";

Comment: Gracias Camilo, ya logre encontrar el error, era un error en la forma de recibir el id

Comment: Genial, estaba en hora de almuerzo y no te había podido contestar, me alegra que encontraras la solución !

Answer (score -1):

```
public function checkOrganismo($id){
    $subtipo = $this->show($id);
    $tipos = Organismo::where('estatus',1)->get();
    $flag=0;
    $cont=0;
   for($c=0; $c < count($tipos);$c++){
        if($tipos[$c]->nombre==$subtipo->nombre) $cont++;
    }
    if($cont>0) $flag=1;

    if($flag==1){
        return view('mivista1', compact('flag'))
    }
    else{
        return view('mivista2', compact('flag'))
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Juan Jose, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su contenido (las preguntas que son sólo código no se consideran buenas). Deberías añadir una pequeña descripción del código compartido: qué hace y cómo funciona. Lee [answer] para más información.